# Spring - form not submitting values to DB

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-mvc

I am making web app in spring. I made simple form to create user with password (For Spring security) and I cannot pass those values to MySql. I've got another working form, so It's not problem with connection. There are no exception in console.

Here's the code.

.jsp file

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

    <%@ taglib prefix="sf" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>



<center><h2>Dodaj Użytkownika</h2>
<sf:form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/usercreate" method="post"
    modelAttribute="users">

    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Nazwa użytkownika</td>
            <td><sf:input path="${username}" name="username"
                    type="text" /><br />
            <div class="error">
                    <sf:errors path="username"></sf:errors>
                </div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="label">Hasło:</td>
            <td><sf:input path="${password}"
                    name="password" type="password" />
                <div class="error">
                    <sf:errors path="password"></sf:errors>
                </div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="label"></td>
            <td><input class="control"  type="submit" value="Dodaj Użytkownika"/></td>
        </tr>
    </table>

</sf:form>
</center>
```

Controller

```
@Controller
public class UserController {

private Servicu servicu;

@Autowired
public void setServicu(Servicu servicu) {
    this.servicu = servicu;
}
@Autowired
PasswordEncoder PasswordEncoder;

@RequestMapping("/users")
public String newUser(Model model){
    model.addAttribute("users", new Users());

    return "users";

}

@RequestMapping(value="/usercreate", method= RequestMethod.POST)
public String userCreated(@ModelAttribute("users") Users users,Model model){


//      if(result.hasErrors()){
//          return "login";
//      }
    model.addAttribute("users", users);

    users.setEnabled(true);
    users.setAuthority("ROLE_USER");

        servicu.create(users);
        servicu.createAuth(users);

    return "home";
}
```

DAO

```
@Component("userDAO")
public class UserDAO {

private NamedParameterJdbcTemplate jdbc;

@Autowired
private PasswordEncoder PasswordEncoder;

@Autowired
public void setPasswordEncoder(PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder) {
    PasswordEncoder = passwordEncoder;
}

@Autowired
public void setDataSource(DataSource jdbc) {
    this.jdbc = new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(jdbc);
}


public boolean createUser(Users users) {

    MapSqlParameterSource params = new MapSqlParameterSource();

    params.addValue("username", users.getUsername());
    params.addValue("password", PasswordEncoder.encode(users.getPassword()));
    params.addValue("enabled", users.isEnabled());

    return jdbc.update("insert into users (username, password,enabled) values (:username, :password,:enabled)",
            params) == 1;

}

public boolean createAuth(Users users) {

    MapSqlParameterSource params = new MapSqlParameterSource();

    params.addValue("username", users.getUsername());

    params.addValue("authority", users.getAuthority());

    return jdbc.update("insert into authorities (username, authority) values (:username, :authority)", params) == 1;
}
```

Temporary spring sec permits to access all jsps, validation tags are erased.

EDIT:

My service file

```
@Service("servicu")
public class Servicu {

    @Autowired
    private OffersDAO offersDAO;
    @Autowired
    private UserDAO userDAO;

    @Autowired
    public void setOffersDAO(OffersDAO offersDAO) {
        this.offersDAO = offersDAO;
    }

    @Autowired
    public void setUserDAO(UserDAO userDAO) {
        this.userDAO = userDAO;
    }

    public List<Hospitals> getCurrent(){
        return offersDAO.getHosps();
    }



    public void create(OrdersPatient ordersPatient) {
        offersDAO.createPatient(ordersPatient);


    }

    public void create(Orders orders) {
        offersDAO.createOrder(orders);

    }

    public void create(Users users) {
        userDAO.createUser(users);

    }

    public void createAuth(Users users) {
        userDAO.createAuth(users);

    }
```

and security context xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"


xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"


xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">


<security:authentication-manager>

    <security:authentication-provider>
        <security:jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"
        authorities-by-username-query='select * from authorities where username = ?'
            users-by-username-query='select * from users where username = ?'
            id="jdbcUserService" />

        <security:password-encoder ref="PasswordEncoder"></security:password-encoder>
    </security:authentication-provider>

</security:authentication-manager>
<security:http use-expressions="true">

    <security:intercept-url pattern="/users" access="permitAll" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/userlist" access="permitAll"  />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/usercreated" access="permitAll"   />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/orderForm" access="permitAll"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/create" access="permitAll" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/showorders" access="permitAll" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/success" access="permitAll" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/login" access="permitAll" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/home" access="permitAll" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/" access="permitAll" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/static/**" access="permitAll" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="denyAll" />

    <security:form-login login-page="/login"
        authentication-failure-url="/login?error=true" />
    <security:logout logout-success-url="/home" />


</security:http>
<bean id="PasswordEncoder"
    class="org.springframework.security.crypto.password.StandardPasswordEncoder">
</bean>
<security:global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled"></security:global-method-security>
```

Comment: First of all, switch your logging to DEBUG for spring. This way at least you will know if HTTP request reaches UserController. Also, you should provide Servicu class source code. It is hard to answer without its code.

Comment: suppose you also share the spring security configurations that may be also needed.

Comment: Is any error being thrown?  if so please share

Comment: I added code from sec. context and service file. There are no errors thrown.

Answer (score 0):

Solution of this problem was trivial. I discovered that I did not put

```
<security:intercept-url pattern="/usercreate" access="permitAll"/>
```

in my security-context.

And this maps to my method. Now everything is working.